# go言語のパッケージiniのimportがうまくいかない

Tags: go

config.iniファイルをロードするためにiniパッケージを用いて以下の様に記述し、mainファイルから呼び出して使おうとしております。

```
package config

import (
    "gopkg.in/ini.v1"
)

func init() {
    cfg, err := ini.Load("config.ini")
    if err != nil {
      //処理
     }
}
```

しかし、実行時にエラーが出て、実行することができません。

**エラーメッセージ:**

```
config/config.go:7:2: cannot find package
```

[go-ini/ini](https://github.com/go-ini/ini) で指示されているように `$ go get gopkg.in/ini.v1` を用いてインストールしております。
どのようにすればエラーが解決するでしょうか。
環境はFedoraです。

**捕捉:**

また、`import ("gopkg.in/ini.v1")` についてコード中に以下のエラーが表示され、そもそもインポートがうまくいってないように思えます。

```
could not import gopkg.in/ini.v1 (cannot find package "gopkg.in/ini.v1" in any of 
    /usr/lib/golang/src/gopkg.in/ini.v1 (from $GOROOT)
    /home/USERNAME/go/src/gopkg.in/ini.v1 (from $GOPATH))
```

Comment: `go get` で `$GOPATH/src` にパッケージがダウンロードされていないという事は Go Modules が有効になっているのかもしれません。`/home/USERNAME/go/pkg/mod/gopkg.in/ini.v1@v1.62.0/` というディレクトリがありませんか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。確認致しましたところ、`/home/USERNAME/go/pkg/mod/gopkg.in/ini.v1@v1.62.0/`がございました。これはどのようにすれば良いでしょうか。

Comment: 手っ取り早い対処法としては Go Modules を無効にして `go get` を再度実行します。`GO111MODULE=off go get gopkg.in/ini.v1` これで `$GOPATH/src` にパッケージがインストールされると思いますが、今後の事を考慮しますと Go Modules へ移行された方がよろしいかと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。Go modulesに移行しようと思います。